# METEOR JS commenting on image on specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor

I'm newbie in METEOR JS. I have multiple Images.on each Image based on the position(x & y co-ordinates) i want to add comment and at which position i have added commented that point has to highlighted.

so when I again come back on image then already commented places should be listed over there.

I tried it but getting co-ordinates of image by the java-script. but that place is not going to highlighted. `Template.testTemplate.events({
    'click img'(e) {

```
function FindPosition(oElement)
{
  if(typeof( oElement.offsetParent ) != "undefined")
  {
    for(var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent)
    {
      posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
      posY += oElement.offsetTop;
    }
      return [ posX, posY ];
    }
    else
    {
      return [ oElement.x, oElement.y ];
    }
}
function GetCoordinates(e)
{
  var PosX = 0;
  var PosY = 0;
  var ImgPos;
  ImgPos = FindPosition(myImg);
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  if (e.pageX || e.pageY)
  {
    PosX = e.pageX;
    PosY = e.pageY;
  }
  else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)
    {
      PosX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
        + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      PosY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
        + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
  PosX = PosX - ImgPos[0];
  PosY = PosY - ImgPos[1];
  console.log(PosX,'PosX',PosY,'PosY')
  document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = PosX;
  document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = PosY;
}


    var myImg = document.getElementById("testImage");
    console.log(myImg,'myImg',e)
    // myImg.onmousedown = GetCoordinates; 

},
});`
```

so basically i required highlighted place where i have commented already on specific position.

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code you've written and help us help you.

Comment: This is a very broad question with many possible answers.

Comment: I have added my javascript code where i can get the x and y co-ordinates
based on that my bussiness logic is done
but regarding ui concern LIke to show it highlighted and on click that co-ordinates i want to send some data so i require to open the popup

Comment: i also tried with https://timseverien.com/taggd/v3/ .. it allows me to add comment on my page but in simple demo but it not working in meteor js